# Switch Statements in Karate

Tags: karate

Do we have any way to use the Switch statement conditions in karate?

What I want to do:

```
def network = response.list.network
```

network value gets updated for every loop so based up on the network value I need to call a feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

```
* def result = call read('handle-' + network + '.feature')
```